# Issue in Implementing Blocking Queue in java

Tags: java, multithreading

I am implementing a thread-safe Blocking Queue in java but it appears threads are running one after another and not in parallel. Can anyone help me to find out what am I doing wrong? My code is as follows:

```
package com.example;

import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

class Producer implements Runnable{

    BlockingQueue blockingQueue;

    public Producer(BlockingQueue blockingQueue) {
        this.blockingQueue = blockingQueue;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        int counter = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                blockingQueue.enqueue(counter++);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException ex)
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

class Consumer implements Runnable{

    BlockingQueue blockingQueue;

    public Consumer(BlockingQueue blockingQueue) {
        this.blockingQueue = blockingQueue;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {


        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                blockingQueue.dequeue();
            }
            catch (InterruptedException ex)
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        BlockingQueue blockingQueue = new BlockingQueue(10);
        Thread producer = new Thread(new Producer(blockingQueue), "Prod");
        Thread consumer = new Thread(new Consumer(blockingQueue), "Cons");
        producer.start();
        consumer.start();
    }
}

class BlockingQueue {

    private List queue = new LinkedList();
    private int  limit = 10;

    public BlockingQueue(int limit){
        this.limit = limit;
    }


    public synchronized void enqueue(Object item)
            throws InterruptedException  {

        while(this.queue.size() == this.limit) {
            System.out.println("Wait Enque : "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
            wait();
        }

        Thread.sleep(1000);
        System.out.println("Add Item : " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        this.queue.add(item);
        notifyAll();
    }


    public synchronized Object dequeue()
            throws InterruptedException{

        while(this.queue.size() == 0){
            System.out.println("Wait Denque : "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
            wait();
        }

        Thread.sleep(1000);
        System.out.println("Remove Item : " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        notifyAll();
        return this.queue.remove(0);
    }

}
```

I am new to multithreading.

This is the output I am getting:

```
Add Item : Prod
Add Item : Prod
Add Item : Prod
Add Item : Prod
Add Item : Prod
Add Item : Prod
Add Item : Prod
Add Item : Prod
Add Item : Prod
Add Item : Prod
Wait Enque : Prod
Remove Item : Cons
Remove Item : Cons
Remove Item : Cons
Remove Item : Cons
Remove Item : Cons
Remove Item : Cons
Remove Item : Cons
Remove Item : Cons
Remove Item : Cons
Remove Item : Cons
Wait Denque : Cons
Add Item : Prod
Add Item : Prod
Add Item : Prod
```

Comment: You might want to show some of the output you are getting; from a first glance, your code looks OK.

Comment: He provides his own class BlockingQueue. Maybe that is bad naming; but not really problem.

Comment: yes i edited my question

Comment: @Qasim Is my answer below clear enough?

Comment: Have a look at better implementation of BlockingQueue : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37683895/wait-and-notify-in-consumer-and-producer-threads/37686902#37686902

Answer (score 2):

Your implementation of `BlockingQueue` demonstrates the "Sleeping at Work" pattern that should be avoided.

For some reason, you decided to call `Thread.sleep` in your data structure's `synchronized` methods `enqueue and dequeue`. I don't think that is required at all. What those methods should do at a minimum is to use the shared mutable state (i.e. your `queue`) in a thread-safe manner. And everything except the call to `Thread.sleep()` in those methods is a good first attempt:

```
public synchronized void enqueue(Object item)
        throws InterruptedException {

    while (this.queue.size() == this.limit) {
        System.out.println("Wait Enque : "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
        wait();
    }

    System.out.println("Add Item : " + item.toString() + " " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    this.queue.add(item);
    notifyAll();
}
```

and similarly for `dequeue`.

What your threads however are doing is they are being extremely greedy :-). Maybe you should actually do something with the dequeued item *inside the run method* of your threads:

```
    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            Object deq = blockingQueue.dequeue();
            Thread.sleep(1000); // sleeping to simulate using the de-queued item

        }
        catch (InterruptedException ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

So, in effect, all I did was take the *sleeping* part out of your data structure's methods. And I get the following output which is interleaved and something that I'd expect:

```
Add Item : 0 Prod
Remove Item : 0 Cons
Add Item : 1 Prod
Remove Item : 1 Cons
Add Item : 2 Prod
Add Item : 3 Prod
Remove Item : 2 Cons
Add Item : 4 Prod
Add Item : 5 Prod
```

Of course, there are several improvements that one can suggest:

1. Make all your fields `final`.
2. Use something like `CountDownLatch` to ensure some fairness.

Take a look at `java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue` for some insights as well!

Answer (score 0):

You get this behavior because when we use `synchronized blocks` also called `intrinsic locks`, we have no guarantee which one of the waiting thread will get the lock first (the `intrinsic lock` is an `unfair` lock). To get the behavior that you expect, you need to use a `fair explicit lock`, this way you are sure that the first thread waiting for the lock will acquire it first. Here is how you create a `fair explicit lock` with its corresponding `condition`:

```
class BlockingQueue {

    private final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock(true);
    private final Condition condition = lock.newCondition();
    ...
```

The code of enqueue will then be:

```
public void enqueue(Object item)
    throws InterruptedException  {

    try {
        lock.lock();
        while(this.queue.size() == this.limit) {
            System.out.println("Wait Enque : "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
            condition.await();
        }

        Thread.sleep(1000);
        System.out.println("Add Item : " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        this.queue.add(item);
        condition.signalAll();
    } finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }
}
```

And finally the code of dequeue will be:

```
public Object dequeue()
    throws InterruptedException{

    try {
        lock.lock();
        while(this.queue.size() == 0){
            System.out.println("Wait Denque : "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
            condition.await();
        }

        Thread.sleep(1000);
        System.out.println("Remove Item : " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        condition.signalAll();
        return this.queue.remove(0);
    } finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }
}
```

The output is then:

```
Add Item : Prod
Remove Item : Cons
Add Item : Prod
Remove Item : Cons
Add Item : Prod
Remove Item : Cons
Add Item : Prod
Remove Item : Cons
Add Item : Prod
Remove Item : Cons
Add Item : Prod
Remove Item : Cons
Add Item : Prod
Remove Item : Cons
```